# Which is faster; adding to pandas dataframe then extract to cvs or writing to document with file pointer

Tags: python, pandas, performance, runtime

I have a really big data that I am processing about 500k query pairs. I believe performance of my code would be effected by the writing method I use since all the other functions runs in average O(n) or O(1). I also run my code with out doing any write or output. It considerably faster. So I am looking for a fast way to write to a txt/cvs/tvs/* file.

I am using Python3 and reading data from a list. After processing, I can append it to a pandas dataframe or just write it to an output file using file pointer .write method.

So, considering these two options down below. Which one would be faster. Or what's the fastest way.

```
really_big_data = [1, 2, 3, 4]

# Approach 1
f = open('results.cvs', 'w')
for i in really_big_data:
    if i % 2 == 0:
        f.write("%d,even\n" % i)
    else:
        f.write("%d,odd\n" % i)
f.close()

# Approach 2
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Int', 'O/E'])
for i in really_big_data:
    if i % 2 == 0:
        df.append(pd.DataFrame({'Int': i, 'O/E': 'even'}))
    else:
        df.append(pd.DataFrame({'Int': i, 'O/E': 'odd'}))
df.to_csv('results.cvs')
```

Comment: Appending to a dataframe is awful, lots of memory must be copied. Your first block of code should be faster. But you could also store the results in a nested list and use the `csv` module to `writerows`. The buffering of the writes might speed things up.

Comment: Now, I did some experiment and it looks like df is awful. Thank you.

Comment: Awful for _appending_. The underlying numpy arrays get copied to keep contiguous blocks of memory. They're not designed to change size.